# Rendering a react component in Ruby on Rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, partials, react-rails

Is it possible to render a react component in a rails partial through an AJAX call? Basically for performance reasons, I have to do some condition checks in order to render and initialize a react component in rails view. I cannot require the react JS upfront as well. I am thinking about rendering a partial through AJAX call and replacing the html in the view from jQuery. I am using `react-rails` for this purpose.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it. Other alternatives would be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

checked `react-rails` source code and had to manually call `ReactRailsUJS.handleMount()` via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For me, calling `ReactRailsUJS.mountComponents()` fixed my issue.